# How to store file in google drive without logged in through login dialog using java and google api

Tags: java, google-api

How to store file in google drive without logged in through login dialog using java and google api

Comment: So I don't really understand the 'question'. Should the user first choose a file and then login with his credentials in a dialog?

Comment: by providing any file path statically and store programetically using google api and java

Comment: Okay, what have you tried? Have you build a user interface via [Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) or something? Do you have a problem with the [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/)?

Comment: Did you read this https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-java

Comment: Not sure I understand you, but if you want to know how your app can use the Drive API without you having to logging in on the browser, you can use a service account. There's an authentication example in Java here: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/service-accounts

Comment: i tried service account also it gives com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "error" : "invalid_grant"
}
 at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:105)

Comment: String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = "1009761453997-v5sb6sv6q3hc6oipclsem36cqec9om0s@developer.gserviceaccount.com"  String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH = "C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\3af24a9b04a8073f8c1c4c648af5c1ab83f964a0-privatekey.p12";
GoogleCredential credential;try {credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(httpTransport).setJsonFactory(jsonFactory).setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL).setServiceAccountScopes(DriveScopes.all()).setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new java.io.File(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH)).build();